# java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission preferences)

Tags: java, lotus-domino, accesscontrolexception

I'm trying to run an Java agent from the console of the server and I get this Exception:

```
Agent Manager: Agent printing: WARN  AppLogger.java:246 initialize() Could not find a log4j.properties resource! Defaulting to app.log output. 
Agent Manager: Agent  error: Exception in thread "AgentThread: FTPBB" 
Agent Manager: Agent  error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at com.bloomberg.datalic.api.ExtendedFTPConnection.<clinit>(ExtendedFTPConnection.java:2780)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at FTP.<init>(FTP.java:93)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at FTPBB.NotesMain(FTPBB.java:110)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error: Caused by: 
Agent Manager: Agent  error: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission preferences)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:108)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot(Preferences.java:443)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at com.bloomberg.datalic.util.DLPreferencesTree.<init>(DLPreferencesTree.java:29)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at com.bloomberg.datalic.util.DLPreferencesTree.getInstance(DLPreferencesTree.java:44)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at com.bloomberg.datalic.util.DLPreferenceNode.<clinit>(DLPreferenceNode.java:19)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  ... 8 more
```

The agent uses two external jar-libraries from Bloomberg. These two are imported into the agent and also placed in the domino/jvm/lib directory on the server.

The exception is thrown when calling the class constructor of one of the classes in the imported library.

The agent runs fine when running it manually in the Designer client.

I think I must edit java.pol* files but my experience here i quite limited, I'm afraid…

Please advice

/Mike

Comment: I should add that the files are in the jvm/lib/ext directory.
Also I have a java.pol file with the following grant:
grant { 
 permission java.security.AllPermission;

};
This file is enabled in the java.security file

Comment: Also the security level of the agent is set to 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now figured this out.
The java.pol file is not used at all, despite the java.security file states it should be included.

To make this work you need to change the java.policy file instead.
This I might say is not the preferred solution since the .pol file should be left for user added grants and the .policy file is the default Domino JVM file.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the *preferences* RuntimePermission:

> java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission **preferences**)

The minimum you need to do is *add* a RuntimePermission to your policy file:

```
grant {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "preferences";
};
```

Once you get past this exception, you'll probably get more, but it's better than allowing all permissions.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't solve the problem. I get the same exception.

Comment: My java.security file:
policy.url.1=file:${java.home}/lib/security/java.policy
policy.url.2=file:${java.home}/lib/security/java.pol
policy.url.3=file:///${user.home}/.java.policy

My java.pol file:


grant { 
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "preferences";
};

Answer (score 0):

Open `java.policy` document stored in `[JAVA]\jvm\lib\security`
And add this statements within "grant" section:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.*";
```